# How to force outer join with .Include query Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, outer-join

My data model is below. `UserPhone` is required but navigation property is optional as long as `User`'s table could be empty:

```
public class Request
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [Required]
    public string UserPhone {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("UserPhone")]
    public virtual User User {get;set;}
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string UserPhone {get;set;}
}
```

The `User`s table is populated after a request is entered into the system. And somewhere between the request is entered and the user is not populated I'm trying to fetch all the requests with a user, if exists (outer join).

```
db.Requests.Include(r=>r.User).FirstOrDefault();
```

Which gives me zero results because EF did inner join (my `UserPhone` field is defined and a foreign key and it is required for the Requests table).

How can I properly define the mapping to be able to use include mapping? I need the `include` because my case touched several more tables I would like to do all with manual joins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does `INNER JOIN` because you have configured the FK property as [`Required`]. So from EF point of view the related `User` record should always exist.

If that's not the case, it means your model and database are out of sync. Remove the [`Required`] annotation from the `Request.UserPhone` property and you are done.

**Update:** EF relies heavily to the model metadata provided through conventions, data annotations and fluent configuration. All the decisions are made based on that information. For instance, when you configure a persistent primitive property as required, all the `null` checks against that property in the query will be removed and resolved at query translation time to either constant `true` or `false`. The same applies to relationships. Inside queries (and `Include` is a specific query construct) they are used by EF to determine the cardinality of the joins and the *type* of the joins. When querying the *one* side of the relationship, the `Required` / `Optional` property of the FK controls whether a `INNER` or `LEFT OUTER` join is generated.

So the only way to control EF behaviors is by supplying it with correct metadata from the entity model. There is no way to dynamically control / alter the behavior of a specific operations.

Comment: I mentioned that my data model is defined as per requirements. My `request` table requires the `userPhone` to be defined (required). Same time Users table doesn't require user to be present (outer join). SO the question is how to tell EF not to do inner join.

Comment: I already told you. It doesn't matter what is your business/domain model requirement. EF "entity" model represents the storage model and FK relationship, thus should reflect the database table `NULL` / `NOT NULL` and FK constraints. This is EF **requirement**, if you don't follow it (lie EF), don't expect EF to produce correct queries for you.

Comment: `I already told you` - no you don't. Your answer confirms that I should update my datamodel when I stated that it's my requirement. The answer in comment make more sense when you confirmed that this is EF requirement. You should put it in the answer.

Comment: Ah, sorry (English is not my natural language) - I thought it's obvious :) Apologies and let me think a bit how to formulate it better.